# Add comma in array first element in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array in Ruby on Rails.

```
[city, state, zip].reject(&:blank?).join(' ')
```

I want to add comma after first element of an array i.e city

```
"Atlanta, GA 30114"
```

Comment: maybe something like `['Atlanta', 'GA', '30114'].insert(1, ',').reject(&:blank?).join(' ')` but untested

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen If first element is blank then comma should not show.

Comment: What if it is such array? `[nil, 'GA', '30114']` — what is expected output?

Comment: @mechnicov It should display like GA 30114

Comment: Is `city` actually `nil` or merely an empty string `""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lots of ways to do it... here's another...

```rb
city,state,zip = ["Atlanta","GA","30114"]
[(city+"," if city),state,zip].compact.join(" ") => "Atlanta, GA 30114"
```

when city is blank:

```rb
city,state,zip = [nil,"GA","30114"]
[(city+"," if city),state,zip].compact.join(" ") => "GA 30114"
```

Comment: `reject(&:blank?)` will handle empty strings. It is unclear if `city` is actually `nil` or simply `""`

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6.1 introduced [`Enumerable#compact_blank`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank). You can use it instead of `reject(&:blank?)`

If you need add comma only after the city, just add comma to the city if it is present

```rb
def format_city(city, state, zip)
  city_with_comma = "#{city}," if city.present?
  [city_with_comma, state, zip].compact_blank.join(" ")
end
```

```rb
format_city(nil, "GA", "30114")
# => "GA 30114"

format_city("Atlanta", "GA", "30114")
# => "Atlanta, GA 30114"
```

Comment: This is the only post so far that addresses city as an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 0):

To add a comma after the first element of an array in Ruby on Rails:

```
result = [array[0], array[1..-1].reject(&:blank?).join(' ')].join(', ')
puts result
```

`reject(&:blank?)` Ensures that any blank or empty elements are removed from the resulting array.

`join(', ')` combines the elements of the array into a string, separated by a comma and space

`result` variable will hold the desired output: "Atlanta, GA 30114", with a comma after the city name.

**Interesting fact:**

`blank?` Is commonly used in Ruby on Rails instead of `empty?` which is commonly used in default Ruby

Comment: Might want to test with `array = [nil, 'GA', '30114']` or `array = ["", 'GA', '30114']`